# OpenCV display multiple unwanted window even though the name is same

Tags: c++, opencv

So I got this problem when I tried to run this code -

```
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 0
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap("VfE_html5.mp4");
    if (!cap.isOpened())  
        return -1;
    namedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat frame;
    while(1)
    {
        cap >> frame; 
        if (frame.empty()) return 0;
        imshow("video", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0) return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After running this code in my visual studio, it did show up the video but with 2 window appearing which the first one is the video and the second one just a blank grey color window.
[OpenCV compile result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfnEc.png)

Also if I want to close the video I will get this-
[Error Exception Thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtVkS.png)

so did anyone has any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: `if (frame.empty()) break;` and `if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry already tried  that not working, still making the same output

Comment: Just for kicks, try building and running a `Release Build` rather than a `Debug Build`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Man you are a genius. Thanks. i never thinking that changing form debug to release can solve a problem. the grey window behind the video window is gone now but the window can't be close when i click the x button. it close the window and just pop up back to the screen.

Comment: You need to add a keyboard press to destroy the opnecv window. After waitkey, instead of return, add break and outside loop add destroyAllWindows().

Comment: As @MarkSetchell hints at, you're linking with the wrong library in debug mode. The call stack in your second image clearly shows you using `opencv_world330.dll`. This is a runtime library, the debug one has `d` suffix in the name. The debug and release runtimes are incompatible, and mixing them tends to end with a boom. Don't do it.

Comment: @I.Newton i already add it. it just close when i type any key on my keyboard but i can't close it with x button on the window. is this normal?

Comment: @DanMašek yes, i already do as you say. previously i just add both opencv_world330.dll and opencv_world330d.dll in the debug runtimes. i didn't notice that it run using the release without the d behind the 330. Thanks